# How to pass Text Input Results to multiple screens in Kivy using .kv language only

Tags: python, kivy, label, screen, textinput

Please see both .py and .kv files below.  (I apologize if I am violating any formatting rules).  My program below only passes my Text Input to the MainPage Label.  However, I'd like to pass the Text Input from the MainPage to multiple pages, in their respective Labels, using only .kv language.  Is there a way to do this?

---

---

### TestFunction2.py

---

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class MainPage(Screen, Widget):
    pass

class Interior(Screen, Widget):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("textFunction2.kv")

class AwesomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

### TestFunction2.kv

---

```
WindowManager:
    MainPage:
    Interior:

<MainPage>:
    name: "MainPage"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Button:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            text: "Main"
            color: 0,1,0,1
            size_hint: .2, None  # is a percentage of the proportion
            #width: "80dp"
            height: "60dp"
            pos_hint: {"x": .2, "y": .9}  #x, center_x, right    y, center_y, top
            font_size: "15dp"
            on_release: app.root.current = "MainPage"

        Button:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            text: "Interior"
            color: 0,1,0,1
            size_hint: .2, None  # is a percentage of the proportion
            #width: "80dp"
            height: "60dp"
            pos_hint: {"x": .2, "y": .9}  #x, center_x, right    y, center_y, top
            font_size: "15dp"
            on_release: app.root.current = "Interior"

    TextInput:
        id: my_text_input
        text: ""
        size_hint: .2,  .05
        #width: "200dp"
        #height: "30dp"
        pos_hint: {"x": .4, "y": .06}  #x, center_x, right    y, center_y, top
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: my_label.text = my_text_input.text

    Label:
        id: my_label
        text: "-----"
        color: 0,1,0,1
        size_hint: .2, None  # is a percentage of the proportion
        #width: "200dp"
        height: "60dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "y": .72}  #x, center_x, right    y, center_y, top
        #font_size: 32

    Label:
        text: "Go 2 Green  Installation  App"
        color: 0,1,0,1
        size_hint: .2, None  # is a percentage of the proportion
        #width: "120dp"
        height: "60dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "y": .8}  #x, center_x, right    y, center_y, top
        #font_size: 30

<Interior>:
    name: "Interior"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Button:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            text: "Main"
            color: 0,1,0,1
            size_hint: .2, None  # is a percentage of the proportion
            #width: "80dp"
            height: "60dp"
            pos_hint: {"x": .2, "y": .9}  #x, center_x, right    y, center_y, top
            font_size: "15dp"
            on_release: app.root.current = "MainPage"

        Button:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            text: "Interior"
            color: 0,1,0,1
            size_hint: .2, None  # is a percentage of the proportion
            #width: "80dp"
            height: "60dp"
            pos_hint: {"x": .2, "y": .9}  #x, center_x, right    y, center_y, top
            font_size: "15dp"
            on_release: app.root.current = "Interior"

    Label:
        id: my_label
        text: "-----"
        color: 0,1,0,1
        size_hint: .2, None  # is a percentage of the proportion
        #width: "200dp"
        height: "60dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "y": .72}  #x, center_x, right    y, center_y, top
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add an `id` for the `MainPage`:

```
WindowManager:
    MainPage:
        id: mp
    Interior:
```

Then you can use that in your `<Interior>` rule:

```
Label:
    id: my_label
    text: root.manager.ids.mp.ids.my_text_input.text
```

Comment: John, Not sure if you received my thank you so I'm posting it again.